# Evenly space horizontal navigation items

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation

I've finally gotten my longer nav bar items to all display horizontally instead of stacking vertically, but I cannot get them to space evenly with the shorter items across my container. I've tried a number of things I've researched to no avail. Any ideas?

Thanks you!

Menu CSS:

```
#myslidemenu {
padding-top: 10px;
}
.jqueryslidemenu{
width: 100%;
}

.jqueryslidemenu ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

/*Top level list items*/
.jqueryslidemenu ul li{
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  z-index:100;
  float:left;
}

.jqueryslidemenu ul li.first a {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0; 
}
/*Top level menu link items style*/
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a{
display:block;
width:115px;
padding:4px 0px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 20px;
outline: none;
text-align:left;
font-size: 12px;
color:#7c7c7c;
}

* html .jqueryslidemenu ul li a{ /*IE6 hack to get sub menu links to behave correctly*/
display: inline-block;
}

.jqueryslidemenu ul li a:link, .jqueryslidemenu ul li a:visited{
color: #7c7c7c;
}

.jqueryslidemenu ul li a:hover,
.jqueryslidemenu ul li.selected a,
.jqueryslidemenu ul li.current_page_item a {
color: #2a7ea0;
}

/*1st sub level menu*/
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
border:1px solid #cbcbcb;
border-right:none;
}

/*Sub level menu list items (undo style from Top level List Items)*/
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li{
display: list-item;
z-index: 99999;
}

/*All subsequent sub menu levels vertical offset after 1st level sub menu */
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li ul{
border-right:none;
top: 0;
}

/* Sub level menu links style */
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li a,
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li a:link, 
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li a:visited{
width: 160px; /*width of sub menus*/
margin: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
background: #fff;
color: #999999;
padding:8px 20px;
font-size: 16px;
}

.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li a:hover{ /*sub menus hover style*/
background: #EAEAEA;
color: #2a7ea0;
}

/* ######### CSS classes applied to down and right arrow images  ######### */

.downarrowclass{
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
right: 7px;
display: none;
}

.rightarrowclass{
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: 5px;
display: none;
}

#menu-wrapper {
height: 69px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 990px;

}
#menu-container {
  height: 67px;
width: 990px; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #E6E6DC;
border-top:1px solid #ffffff;
border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;

}
```

Or here: http://pastebin.com/0pf9u70D

Live site: http://mefo1.ecin1prod1lnx1.com/

Comment: Please post your code in your question directly (Using SO' markdown syntax). :)

Comment: @mac thanks for looking! see edits above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should fix your issues:

**Remove the padding-right found in many of your menu items.**

Many of the menu items, specifically the `<a>` tags, have a `padding-right: 23px;`

**Make the following change to your CSS:**

```
.jqueryslidemenu ul li a
{
     width: auto;              
     margin: 0 20px 0 20px;    //Adjust this to fit your needs.
     ...
}
```

This would make each item evenly spaced based on the width of the menu items.

**You should be able to use the following script, simply place it in the head section of your page and this should fix your issue:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    for(i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item-object-page').length; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item-object-page')[i].firstChild.style.paddingRight = "0px";}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's so close! I realize this is likely a moronic question, but I'm teaching myself all of this. Where are you see padding-right: 23px;? It's not in my style sheet.

Comment: It looks like it is hard coded, and judging by how some of the code looks it appears most of it is automatically generated. For example : <a href="http://mefo1.ecin1prod1lnx1.com/business-information/" style="padding-right: 23px; ">

Comment: Are you using something specific to generate your menu?

Comment: Aha, I'm regretting using a theme more and more ;). I was avoiding creating a new nav from scratch but it looks as if I am going to get some more practice. Thank you for your help, this will help a lot.

Comment: No problem - if you know how to use jQuery you may be able to change all of those padding values to 0 upon page load. I could write you a small script that could handle that, you might could include it and it could fix your issue

Comment: I don't unfortunately, however, I suppose I could figure out how to apply a small script. Or is that like an ant attempting to climb Everest?

Comment: I'll throw a short edit into the answer that should help you, hope it helps :)