# evenly space horizontal navigation ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists, margin

Can someone help me figure out how to evenly space my ul inside of my navigation?  I basically want about 5px of padding on the right and left and then I want the text to evenly space throughout the remaining space.

```
body {
        background: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        line-height: 25px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

h1 {
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #007a3d;
    }

a:link {
    color: #007a3d;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

a:visited {
    color: #007a3d;
    }
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    }

#container #godbar {
    width: 960px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: url(images/godbar_bg.jpg) repeat-x;
    border-left: 1px solid #dbc25e;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbc25e;
    border-right: 1px solid #dbc25e;
    }

#container #godbar #godbarIcons {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;

    }

#container #godbar #godbarIcons ul {
    display: inline;
    }
#container #godbar #godbarIcons li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right:13px;
}


<!--END GODBAR-->

#container #header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 150px;
}
#container #header #logo h1{
    width: 233px;
    height: 94px;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
    background: url(images/logo.jpg) no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    }

#container #header #logo h1 a {
    display: block;
    width: 233px;
    height: 94px;
    }

#container ul#nav {
    height: 44px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(images/navigation_bg.jpg) repeat-x;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    }

#container ul#nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

#container ul#nav li {
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

#container ul#nav a {
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;

    }
    <body>
<div id="container">
    <!--GODBAR-->
    <div id="godbar">
        <div id="godbarIcons">
        <ul>

            <li id="godbarFacebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/hilounge" target="_blank"><img src="images/godbar_fb.png" alt="hilounge on Facebook" /></a>

            </li>

            <li id="godbarTwitter"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/hilounge" target="_blank"><img src="images/godbar_twitter.png" alt="hilounge on Twitter"/></a>

            </li> 

            <li id="godbarInstagram"><a href="http://www.instagram.com/hilounge" target="_blank"><img src="images/godbar_instagram.png" alt="hilounge on Instagram" /></a>

            </li>
            <li id="godbarPinterest"><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/hilounge" target="_blank"><img src="images/godbar_pinterest.png" alt="hilounge on Pinterest" /></a>

            </li>
            <li id="godbarGplus"><a href="https://plus.google.com/b/108830451064104477365/108830451064104477365/posts" target="_blank"><img src="images/godbar_gplus.png" alt="hilounge on Goolge plus" /></a>

            </li>
            <li id="godbarRss"><a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/hilounge" target="_blank"><img src="images/godbar_rss.png" alt="hilounge RSS feed" /></a>

            </li>
            <li id="godbarEmail"><a href="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=hilounge&amp;loc=en_US" target="_blank"><img src="images/godbar_email.png" alt="hilounge email" /></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <!--END GODBARICONS-->
    </div>
     <!--END GODBAR-->

     <!--BEGIN HEADER-->
     <div id="header">

        <!--BEGIN LOGO-->
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><a href="index.html">hiLounge</a></h1>
        </div>
        <!--END LOGO-->
        <!--BEGIN NAVIGATION-->
        <ul id="nav">
            <h2 class="nav"><li><a href="#"> News </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Entertainment </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Fashion </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Munchies </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Design </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Reviews </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contests </a></li>
            </h2>

        </ul>
        <!--END NAVIGATION-->
     </div>
     <!--END HEADER-->

     <!--BEGIN CAROUSEL-->
     <div id="carousel">
        <ul>
            <a href="#">Previous</a>
            <li><a href="#">Slide 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Slide 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Slide 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Slide 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Slide 5</a></li>
            <a href="#">Next</a>
        </ul>
     </div>     
     <!--END CAROUSEL-->

     <!--BEGIN MAIN-->
  <div id="primaryContent">
    <h1><a href="#"> 10 Best Bongs You Wish You Made</a></h1>
     <a href="#"><img src="images/featured-post-featured-image.png" alt="Post Title" /></a>

     <!--BEGIN POSTMETADATA-->
     <div id="postMetaData">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="images/date-icon.jpg" /> March 26, 2013</li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/category-icon.jpg"  /> Entertainment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/author-icon.jpg"  /> James Scaggs</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <!--END POSTMETADATA-->
     <p>
     In Half Baked, the MacGyver smoker stereotype really taught us that pot smokers can engineer some of the best bongs around when there’s nothing to smoke out of. There’s an art to taking shit from the kitchen, garage, and office and...
     <a href="#"> Read More</a>
     </p>
     <!--BEGIN POSTSHARINGBUTTONS-->
     <div id="postSharingButtons">
        <ul>
            <li>Like</li>
            <li>Tweet</li>
            <li>G+</li>
            <li>Pin it</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <!--END POSTSHARINGBUTTONS-->

     <a href="#"><img src="images/read-more.jpg" /> Read More </a>

    <!-- BEGIN RECENTPOSTS-->

     <h2>Recent Posts</h2>

    <div id="recentPosts">

     <h1><a href="#">5 MUST FOLLOW MARIJUANA FACEBOOK PAGES</a></h1>
     <img src="images/featured-image-1.png" alt="post-title" />

     <!--BEGIN RECENTPOSTMETADATA-->
     <div id="recentPostMetaData">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="images/date-icon.jpg" /> March 26, 2013</li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/category-icon.jpg"  /> Entertainment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/author-icon.jpg"  /> James Scaggs</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <!--END RECENTPOSTMETADATA-->
        <p>
     In Half Baked, the MacGyver smoker stereotype really taught us that pot smokers can engineer some of the best bongs around when there’s nothing to smoke out of. There’s an art to taking shit from the kitchen, garage, and office and...
     <a href="#"> Read More</a>
        </p>

        <!--BEGIN POST SHARING BUTTONS-->

        <div id="postSharingButtons">
            <ul>
                <li>Like</li>
                <li>Tweet</li>
                <li>G+</li>
                <li>Pin it</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--END POST SHARING BUTTONS-->

        <h1><a href="#">7 MARIJUANA INFOGRAPHICS YOU DON'T WANT TO MISS</a></h1>
     <img src="images/featured-image-1.png" alt="post-title" />

     <!--BEGIN RECENTPOSTMETADATA-->
     <div id="recentPostMetaData">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="images/date-icon.jpg" /> March 26, 2013</li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/category-icon.jpg"  /> Entertainment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/author-icon.jpg"  /> James Scaggs</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <!--END RECENTPOSTMETADATA-->
        <p>
     In Half Baked, the MacGyver smoker stereotype really taught us that pot smokers can engineer some of the best bongs around when there’s nothing to smoke out of. There’s an art to taking shit from the kitchen, garage, and office and...
     <a href="#"> Read More</a>
        </p>

        <!--BEGIN POST SHARING BUTTONS-->

        <div id="postSharingButtons">
            <ul>
                <li>Like</li>
                <li>Tweet</li>
                <li>G+</li>
                <li>Pin it</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--END POSTSHARINGBUTTONS-->

    </div>
    <!--END RECENTPOSTS-->

  </div>
     <!--END MAIN-->

</div>
<!--END CONTAINER-->

<div id="footerWrap">

  <div id="footer">

    <div id="footerLogo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/footer-logo.jpg" alt="hiLounge" /></a>
      </div> <!--end footerLogo-->

    <p>
    <a href="#">About Us</a>
    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="#">Legal</a>
    <a href="#">Advertising</a>
    </p>

    <p id="footerInfo">copyright (c) 2013  <a href="http://www.hilounge.com">hiLounge</a>
    </p>

    </div>
    <!--END FOOTER-->

</div>
<!--END FOOTERWRAP-->


</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405616/evenly-space-horizontal-navigation-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately without the images I'm unsure what the exact size of your navigation buttons need to be so I cannot test the code you posted to get the padding/spacing that you want.

```
#container #godbar #godbarIcons ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#container #godbar #godbarIcons li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

try changing this in your css and adjust the left and right padding & margins of the list items until you achieve what you wanted

Comment: Ok thank you.  I've updated the CSS as you noted and it's almost spaced perfectly.  I'm going to keep styling the rest of the html and come back to fix the little details a little later.  Thank you!